# Elixir, what is this program doing?

Tags: concurrency, elixir, spawn

I have been given this code by our teacher. I am having trouble following what this code does. This is all I know so far: `[x1, y1 | z1] = Output2.abc(3)` is called, and so function `abc(2)` will spawn a new process assigned as `y`. Then it will send the value 2 to `y`. When it receives 2, I am stuck at what receive is doing. What does `z -> z` mean?

Also, the prof asks what `x1, y1 are. I don't understand where these variables are located in this code. If someone can just guide me through this it would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
defmodule Output2 do
  def abc(x) do
    y = spawn_link(__MODULE__, :n, [self()])
    send y, x
    receive do
      z -> z
    end
  end

  def n(z) do
    receive do
      v -> send z, n(v * v, v)
    end
  end

  defp n(x, x), do: [x]
  defp n(x, y), do: [y | n(x, y + y)]
end

[x1, y1 | z1] = Output2.abc(2)
```

Comment: `x1` and `x2` get set at the very bottom. Although, I don't see where `x2` or `y2` may be getting set. Reference for recursion: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/recursion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Output2.abc(2)` is called.
2. A linked process is started with [spawn_link/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_link-3) using `n(z)` as the receiver

   1. The original process waits for a message from the recently spawned process.
3. The parameter x (i.e. 2) is sent to the process started in #2
4. The process started in #2 sends back the result of `n(v * v, v)`

   1. `n(v * v, v)` is a call to `n(x, y)` because x, and y are different values.
   2. So, we have `n(2*2, 2)`. `n(x,y)` returns a list of `y` concatenated with `n(x, y+y)` where x = 4, and y = 2
   3. From the previous step `n(4, 2+2)` is called, which invokes `n(x, x)` returning a single item list of [4]
   4. From 4.2, [2 | [4]] results in [2 | 4] (a list of two elements: 2, 4)
5. The original process received the list as `z`, and returns `z` (`z -> z`)
6. Pattern matching is used to assign x1 = 2, and y1 = 4. z1 is the tail of the rest, which is empty.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`z -> z` is just like function define: `fun(z) {return z}`
and **z** is parameter which got from **receive** function.